# How to get http response headers using the Glide and OkHttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp, android-glide

I need to get the http response headers from image. How to create a interceptor for each request from Glide? Is it necessary create a Glide Module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frist, you have to integrate Glide and OkHttp using custom `GlideModule` instead of the default one.

Refer [this example](http://arnaud-camus.fr/combining-glide-and-stetho-to-easily-debug-your-image-loading-system/) on how to do that.

Then you have to write an `OkHttp` interceptor to intercept the response information and get the response headers.

Refer this [OkHttp Logging Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) code and you will get an idea on how to intercept the response and get the response headers.

You have to set that interceptor to your `OkHttpClient` (which mostly would be a singleton instance):

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(yourInterceptor).build();
```

That `OkHttpClient` instance has to be passed to your custom `GlideModule` implementation's `registerComponents()` callback:

```
glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory( okHttpClient ));
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: The link in 'this example' is broken.

Answer (score 3):

> You can get response header by intercepting your glide response

```
@GlideModule
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
      override fun applyOptions(context: Context?, builder: GlideBuilder?) {
      }

      override fun registerComponents(context: Context?, glide: Glide?, 
        registry: Registry?) {
            super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry)
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            httpClient.addInterceptor({ chain: Interceptor.Chain? ->
                val response = chain?.proceed(chain.request())
                // for get specific header  
                val header = response?.header("specific header")
                // for get all headers 
                val headers = response?.headers()

                response
            })

            registry?.replace(GlideUrl::class.java, InputStream::class.java, 
            OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(httpClient.build()))
        }
    }
```

If you unable to find any classes like OkHttpUrlLoader then find it
[Here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/integration/okhttp/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/integration/okhttp)

Comment: Actually you can add [this](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/okhttp3.html) to support OkHttpUrlLoader

Comment: I am confused how this can be used from within the GlideApp.load() call? different urls may generate diffeent response headers.